# how to use slide toggle for multipe div tags

Tags: html, jquery-ui

first of all sorry for my weak english, i use slide.toggle function and when i have one element it works good but when i add multiple elements(div tags), it crash or work just for the first element , if i chand the id to a class attribute in javascript , it acts on all element,
but i want to act just on which element has been clicked, and change the size of that element not otherone or all of them,
i searched , and seems `$(this).parent(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();` would be solve my problem, but i dont khow how to set it in javascript, here is the url :`http://itsun.ir/test/`

it's a live demo of my project and problem, can someone help me out fixing this?

and here is codes i use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hs").click(function() {

        if (document.getElementById("container").style.display == 'none') {
            document.getElementById("ad").className =
document.getElementById("ad").className.replace
  ( /(?:^|\s)inactive(?!\S)/g , '' )
            document.getElementById("ad").className = " active";

            document.getElementById("au").className =
document.getElementById("au").className.replace
  ( /(?:^|\s)active(?!\S)/g , '' )
            document.getElementById("au").className = " inactive";

        }else{
            document.getElementById("ad").className =
document.getElementById("ad").className.replace
  ( /(?:^|\s)active(?!\S)/g , '' )
            document.getElementById("ad").className = " inactive";


            document.getElementById("au").className =
document.getElementById("au").className.replace
  ( /(?:^|\s)inactive(?!\S)/g , '' )
            document.getElementById("au").className = " active";

        }


    $(".content").slideToggle("slow");




    });
});
```

and here is html codes:

```
          <div id="wrapper">
              <div class="box" id="box"style="width:95%;">
                <div class="top_bar" style="width:100%; height:40px; background-color:#01afee;">
                                    top bar 1   
                </div>

                <div id="container" class="content" style="display:block;">
                            TExt 1
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="box" id="box"style="width:95%;">
                <div class="top_bar" style="width:100%; height:40px; background-color:#01afee;">
                                    top bar 2  
                </div>

                <div id="container" class="content" style="display:block;">
                            TExt 2
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="box" id="box"style="width:95%;">

                <div class="top_bar" style="width:100%; height:40px; background-color:#01afee;">
                                    top bar 3    
                </div>

                <div id="container" class="content" style="display:block;">
                            TExt 3
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
```